# Centering a Table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a `tabular` environment nested within a `table` environment which I'd like to place horizontally centered. What's the best way to achieve this?

If the right thing to do is use the `\centering` command, should `\centering` enclose the `table` or just the `tablular` environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should use `\centering` within the `table` environment for best results.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is preferable over centering the table environment?

Comment: The `center` environment adds unwanted vertical space.

Comment: My question is about centering the tabular versus the table.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman If you'd like to centre the whole table environment you'd have to use `\begin{center} \end{center}` environment, which is why egreg said that.