# How to center align the whole table?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats

I created a table and it starts from the left and goes all the way to right, which looks really skewed. So I want to center align the whole table but couldn't figure out how to do it. I'm new to latex so I don't know how to use other plugin or macros, but I suppose there's a command for this basic functionality. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Is this a `LaTeX` question or a `TeX` question, the `tex-core` confuses me.

Comment: I assume this is a repost of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102038/how-to-center-align-the-whole-table  should your accounts be merged?

Answer (score 3):

If this is inside a `float` like the `table` environment, I'd suggest

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering % center but don't add vertical space
<your table code>
\caption{...} % caption could also be placed above the table
\label{...} % albel always AFTER \caption
\end{table}
```

Using the `center` environment inside a `float` is not recommended as it adds vertical space above and below, which the float will also do, resulting in too much space.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{center}

your table

\end{center}